# extract day from the first week of year

Tags: date, pyspark, timestamp, dayofweek

I try to extract in pyspark the date of Sunday from every given week in a year. Week and year are in the format yyyyww. This is possible for every week except the first week, in this case, a got a null value. This is the sample code and result.

```
columns = ['id', 'week_year']
vals = [
     (1, 201952),
     (2, 202001),
     (3, 202002),
     (4, 201901),
     (5, 201902)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
+---+---------+
| id|week_year|
+---+---------+
|  1|   201952|
|  2|   202001|
|  3|   202002|
|  4|   201901|
|  5|   201902|
+---+---------+
df = df.withColumn("day", to_timestamp(concat(df.week_year, lit("-Sunday")), 'yyyyww-E'))
```

As a result I got

```
+---+---------+-------------------+
| id|week_year|                day|
+---+---------+-------------------+
|  1|   201952|2019-12-22 00:00:00|
|  2|   202001|               null|
|  3|   202002|2020-01-05 00:00:00|
|  4|   201901|               null|
|  5|   201902|2019-01-06 00:00:00|
+---+---------+-------------------+
```

Do you have an idea, why it does not work for the first week? It is also strange for me that 5.01 and 6.01 are in second week, not in the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the calendar for 2020, the year starts on wednesday, which is in the middle of 1st week and that first week doesn't have a sunday. Same goes for the 2019. That is why 2020-01-05 is coming in the second week.
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok, but in this case, I will never get Sunday 29.12 (there is no such a thing as 201953)

Comment: No, you wouldn't get it as sunday 29 as 201953, instead you would get it as 201952, that is the last week of 2019 and the first week of 2020.

Comment: as you see on my example 201952 is 22.12 not 29.12, this is why I am a bit confused.

Comment: 12-29, 12-30, 12-31 of 2019 are considered to be in the first week of 2020. I think that is why your code is considering 22.12.2019 as 52nd week